# Angular Reactive Form always invalid but not empty

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

My Angular is invalid despite is not empty. If I touched it it becomes invalid and I have to add a blank space to each inputs to make it working. If not the form remains invalid.
I'm working with a C# .NET CORE API.

Component:

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";
import { Room } from "../_models/room";
import { Title, Meta } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RoomService } from "../_services/room.service";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { AlertifyService } from "../_services/alertify.service";
import {
 FormGroup,
 FormControl,
 Validators,
 FormBuilder,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
 selector: "app-room",
 templateUrl: "./room.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./room.component.css"],
})
export class RoomComponent implements OnInit {
 roomID: number;
 room: Room;
 baseTitle = environment.title;
 formGroup: FormGroup;
 titleAlert: string = "This field is required";
 post: any = "";

 constructor(
   private titleService: Title,
   private roomService: RoomService,
   private http: HttpClient,
   private route: ActivatedRoute,
   private router: Router,
   private alertify: AlertifyService,
   private meta: Meta,
   private formBuilder: FormBuilder
 ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
     this.roomID = parseInt(params.get("key"));
   });
   console.log(this.roomID);
   if (this.roomID !== 0) {
     this.getRoom();
     this.createForm();      
   } 
   
 }

 getRoom() {
   this.roomService.getRoom(this.roomID).subscribe(
     (response) => {
       this.room = response;
       if (this.room === null) {
         this.router.navigate(["/"]);
       }
       this.titleService.setTitle(this.room?.name + " - " + this.baseTitle);
     },
     (error) => {
       this.alertify.error(error);
     }
   );
 }

 createForm() {
   this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
     name: [this.room?.name, [Validators.required]],
     address: [this.room?.address, Validators.required],
     postcode: [this.room?.postcode, Validators.required],
     locality: [this.room?.locality, Validators.required],
     validate: "",
   });
 }
 

 onSubmit(post) {
   this.roomService.updateRoom(this.roomID, post).subscribe(
     (response) => {
       this.alertify.success(
         "<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Salle sauvée avec succès!"
       );
       this.room = post;
       if (this.room === null) {
         this.router.navigate(["/"]);
       }
       this.titleService.setTitle(this.room?.name + " - " + this.baseTitle);
     },
     (error) => {
       this.alertify.error(error);
     }
   );
 }

 /*checkPassword(control) {
   let enteredPassword = control.value;
   let passwordCheck = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.{8,})/;
   return !passwordCheck.test(enteredPassword) && enteredPassword
     ? { requirements: true }
     : null;
 }*/

 /*checkInUseEmail(control) {
   // mimic http database access
   let db = ["tony@gmail.com"];
   return new Observable((observer) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       let result =
         db.indexOf(control.value) !== -1 ? { alreadyInUse: true } : null;
       observer.next(result);
       observer.complete();
     }, 4000);
   });
 }*/

 /*getErrorEmail() {
   return this.formGroup.get("email").hasError("required")
     ? "Field is required"
     : this.formGroup.get("email").hasError("pattern")
     ? "Not a valid emailaddress"
     : this.formGroup.get("email").hasError("alreadyInUse")
     ? "This emailaddress is already in use"
     : "";
 }*/

 /*getErrorPassword() {
   return this.formGroup.get("password").hasError("required")
     ? "Field is required (at least eight characters, one uppercase letter and one number)"
     : this.formGroup.get("password").hasError("requirements")
     ? "Password needs to be at least eight characters, one uppercase letter and one number"
     : "";
 }*/
}
```

View:

```html
<div class="container" *ngIf="!post" novalidate>
 <mat-card>
   <mat-card-title *ngIf="roomID !== 0">
     {{ room?.name }}
   </mat-card-title>

   <mat-card-title *ngIf="roomID === 0">
     Ajouter une salle
   </mat-card-title>

   <mat-card-content>
     <form
       [formGroup]="formGroup"
       (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)"
       class="form"
     >
       <mat-form-field class="form-element">
         <input
           matInput
           placeholder="Nom de salle"
           formControlName="name"
           value="{{ room?.name }}"
         />
         <mat-error
           *ngIf="
             !formGroup.controls['name'].valid &&
             formGroup.controls['name'].touched
           "
           >Le nom est requis
         </mat-error>
       </mat-form-field>

       <mat-form-field class="form-element">
         <input
           matInput
           placeholder="Adresse"
           formControlName="address"
           value="{{ room?.address }}"
         />
         <mat-error
           *ngIf="
             !formGroup.controls['address'].valid &&
             formGroup.controls['address'].touched
           "
           >L'adresse est requise
         </mat-error>
       </mat-form-field>

       <mat-form-field class="form-element">
         <input
           matInput
           placeholder="Code postal"
           formControlName="postcode"
           value="{{ room?.postcode }}"
         />
         <mat-error
           *ngIf="
             !formGroup.controls['postcode'].valid &&
             formGroup.controls['postcode'].touched
           "
           >Le code postal est requis
         </mat-error>
       </mat-form-field>

       <mat-form-field class="form-element">
         <input
           matInput
           placeholder="Localité"
           formControlName="locality"
           value="{{ room?.locality }}"
         />
         <mat-error
           *ngIf="
             !formGroup.controls['locality'].valid &&
             formGroup.controls['locality'].touched
           "
           >La localité est requise
         </mat-error>
       </mat-form-field>

       <div class="form-element">
         <button *ngIf="roomID !== 0"
           mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           type="submit"
           class="button"
           [disabled]="!formGroup.valid"
         >
           Modifier
         </button>
         <button *ngIf="roomID === 0"
           mat-raised-button
           color="primary"
           type="submit"
           class="button"
           [disabled]="!formGroup.valid"
         >
           Ajouter
         </button>
       </div>
     </form>
     
   </mat-card-content>
 </mat-card>
</div>
```

Here screenshot of the result:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtFd0.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? I'm a beginner in Angular. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: remove the attribute "value" in your matInput -it's not necesary, they are formControls and you indicate the formControlName-

Comment: @Eliseo  If I do that my inputs are empty. I want they to be filled with a value if there is a value.

Comment: @Eliseo it works if I set a timeout to my API call. But first input is always empty. Despite there is a value

Comment: @Eliseo I found the solution by setting the values directly after I get the API response.

Comment: @Mathlab, yes, the correct way, when you use Reactive forms, is set the value to the reactive form controls (using setValue, pathValue, or create again the formGroup) INSIDE the subscribe function

Comment: @Eliseo yes :D thanks a lot for your help! Much appreciated :D